# Integrals and suprema

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

If I know that$\ X < \sup_iX_i$ for example and if $\ X_i $ and $X$ are integrable then when I integrate both sides, where do I put the integral on the RHS? I know that in some situations you can move the supremum inside and outside according to beppo levi etc but what I want to know is forgetting that, where is it always defined or where should I always put it to start off with before thinking about beppo levi or fatou or anything else?

Comment: What does the inequality mean? Is it pointwise? On a set of full measure? Is the family of functions on the right hand side countable?

Comment: Sorry, So lets say instead, $\ X_i i=1,2,3... $ is a sequence of integrable functions. And X is an integrable function, all on  $(\Omega,F,P)$ a measure space . If $\ X\leq Sup_iX_i.. $

Comment: The supremum of a countable family of measurable functions is measurable. so you can put $\int X\leq\int\sup X_i$. Whether the integra preserves the strict inequality depends on what "<" means. If $X(\omega)<\sup_i X_i(\omega)$ for almost all $\omega$, you can write $\int X<\int\sup_i X_i$,

Answer (score 1):

If $\displaystyle X < \sup_i X_i$ then $\displaystyle \int X \le \int \sup_i X_i$.

You can't say "$<$", but only "$\le$"; in some cases they are equal.

And there are some simple cases where $\displaystyle\sup_i \int X_i$ is not the same as $\displaystyle \int \sup_i X_i$.

For example, suppose
$$
X_1(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }0\le x \le 1/2, \\ 0 & \text{if } 1/2<x\le 1,
\end{cases}
$$
and $X_2 = 1 - X_1$.

Then
$$
\sup_{i\in\{1,2\}} \int_0^1 X_i(x)\,dx = \frac 1 2
$$
and
$$
\int \sup_{i\in\{1,2\}} X_i(x)\,dx = 1.
$$